# getting 2067529716 exception while installing sql server express from command line programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

i am installing the sql server express on the 64 bit machine but i am getting error 2067529716. and my installation did not completed successfully. My command line fine code is

```
 using (var configFile = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(configFile);
                writer.WriteLine("[SQLSERVER2008]");
                writer.WriteLine("INSTANCEID=\"" + instanceName + "\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ACTION=\"Install\"");
                writer.WriteLine("FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION");
                writer.WriteLine("HELP=\"False\"");
                writer.WriteLine("INDICATEPROGRESS=\"False\"");
                writer.WriteLine("QUIET=\"True\"");
                writer.WriteLine("QUIETSIMPLE=\"False\"");
                writer.WriteLine("X86=\"False\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ERRORREPORTING=\"False\"");
                writer.WriteLine("INSTALLSHAREDDIR=\"" + Application.StartupPath + "\"");
                writer.WriteLine("INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR=\"" + Application.StartupPath + "\"");
                writer.WriteLine("INSTANCEDIR=\"" + Application.StartupPath + "\"");
                writer.WriteLine("SQMREPORTING=\"False\"");
                writer.WriteLine("INSTANCENAME=\"" + instanceName + "\"");
                writer.WriteLine("AGTSVCACCOUNT=\"Manual\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE=\"Automatic\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ISSVCACCOUNT=\"NT AUTHORITY\\NetworkService\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE=\"Automatic\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ASCOLLATION=\"Latin1_General_CI_AS\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ASDATADIR=\"Data\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ASLOGDIR=\"Log\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ASBACKUPDIR=\"Backup\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ASTEMPDIR=\"Temp\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ASCONFIGDIR=\"Config\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ASPROVIDERMSOLAP=\"1\"");
                writer.WriteLine("SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=\"Automatic\"");
                writer.WriteLine("FILESTREAMLEVEL=\"0\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ENABLERANU=\"True\"");
                writer.WriteLine("SQLCOLLATION=\"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS\"");
                writer.WriteLine("SQLSVCACCOUNT=\"NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE\"");
                writer.WriteLine("SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=\"" + Environment.MachineName + "\\" + Environment.UserName + "\"");
                writer.WriteLine("SECURITYMODE=\"SQL\"");
                writer.WriteLine("ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=\"False\"");
                writer.WriteLine("TCPENABLED=\"0\"");
                writer.WriteLine("NPENABLED=\"0\"");
                writer.WriteLine("BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=\"Automatic\"");
                writer.WriteLine("RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE=\"Automatic\"");
                writer.WriteLine("RSINSTALLMODE=\"FilesOnlyMode\"");

                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance please help me how to solve this ??

Comment: Why are you using C# to install SQL Server or any software for that matter?  Why not just run the installation setup file?

Comment: really ... strange action with a strange result

Comment: adding total error might help

Comment: and the actual command line you submit - and how you are running your app vs your command line

Comment: actually i want to install sql server along with application at the time of installation. My Installation code is                                                         process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/Q /HIDECONSOLE=\"True\" /SAPWD=\"" + saPassword + "\" /CONFIGURATIONFILE=\"" + configFileName + "\"";